# Nested Attributes: why validate nested models if you're using reject_if?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a rails noobie and I'm trying to sort out the differences between rejecting an instance based on an empty attribute and creating a validation that checks the attribute is present.

Students have many exams. A critical attribute of an exam is the score. Without that, the exam should not be accepted into the database.

My exam model has the following line:

```
validates :score, presence: true
```

My student model has this:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :exams,
:reject_if => proc { |exam| exam['score'].blank? }
```

It seems that the second example quietly "rejects" the exam from being entered into the database, whereas the first example spits out an error message and asks you to try again.

But really, what's the difference here....it seems that they both ultimately block an instance from being entered into the database -- would I ever benefit from including both lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But really, what's the difference here...

The difference is absolute :) You isolate the logic to where it belongs.

What you have in `Exam` model concerns only `Exam` model.

What you define in `Student` model, well, concerns only `Student` model.

This said, say, you have passed the `reject_if` in `Student` model and allow the saving transaction to move forward. It won't save the nested object if it fails validations in its model (`Exam`, which is independent by definition).

> would I ever benefit from including both lines?

Having validations in `Exam` model allows you to avoid saving invalid objects into db, and it has nothing to do with validating nested object creation in `Student` model.

In any way these things are separate, different and have no connection.